# Twilio Output Stream

Tags: javascript, twilio

Im trying to get the audio output stream from a live Twilio call in Javascript.

We have the audioContext `Twilio.Device.audioContext` here, and the audioWorklet `Twilio.Device.audioContext.audioWorklet` here.

Can we use these to somehow grab the speaker audio (what the caller is saying) and then send to webkitSpeechRecognition to live transcript?

Comment: Include all your code.

Comment: There's no code to include, the twilio sdk is hosted so you cant change it, i want to write some code which somehow hooks into their output stream, or into the browser window audio output.

This is the sdk `//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.min.js`

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to write code for you.  See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Live Transcribing Phone Calls using Twilio Media Streams](https://www.twilio.com/blog/live-transcribing-phone-calls-using-twilio-media-streams-and-google-speech-text)